# Another pojo class is not creating table in database in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

TrainingDays.java

```
package com.hibernate;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TrainingDays")
public class TrainingDays {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int TD_Id;

    private String T_Days;

    public int getTD_Id() {
        return TD_Id;
    }

    public void setTD_Id(int tD_Id) {
        TD_Id = tD_Id;
    }

    public String getT_Days() {
        return T_Days;
    }

    public void setT_Days(String t_Days) {
        T_Days = t_Days;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="TD_Id")
    private Set<TrainingTime> trainingTime;

    public Set<TrainingTime> getTrainingTime() {
        return trainingTime;
    }

    public void setTrainingTime(Set<TrainingTime> trainingTime) {
        this.trainingTime = trainingTime;
    }

}
```

TrainingTime.java

```
    package com.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TrainingTime")
public class TrainingTime {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int TT_Id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TD_Id")
    private TrainingDays trainingDays;

    private String time;

    private String desc;

    public int getTT_Id() {
        return TT_Id;
    }

    public void setTT_Id(int tT_Id) {
        TT_Id = tT_Id;
    }

    public TrainingDays getTrainingDays() {
        return trainingDays;
    }

    public void setTrainingDays(TrainingDays trainingDays) {
        this.trainingDays = trainingDays;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
    <property name="connection.username">blueHeaven</property>
    <property name="connection.password">123456</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>


    <mapping class="com.hibernate.Rodie" />
    <mapping class="com.hibernate.TrainingTime" />
    <mapping class="com.hibernate.TrainingDays" />


</session-factory>
```

In the database TraningDays table is created but traningTime table is not created.

Can any one help?

Comment: when you start the applciation , did you have an error?

Comment: You miss a `mappedBy = "trainingDays"` in the @OneToMany in `TrainingDays `.

Comment: this error comes after adding your code

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your code as given:

**class TrainingDays**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TrainingDays")
public class TrainingDays {

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "trainingDays")
    private Set<TrainingTime> trainingTime;

}
```

**class TrainingTime**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TrainingTime")
public class TrainingTime {


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TD_Id")
    private TrainingDays trainingDays;

}
```

> You need to specify "mappedBy" when you are creating bidirectional
>   relationship.

Comment: I tried you code as well but still it is not creating TrainingTime table in DB.

Answer (score 0):

As the mapping is bidirectional. Please try like this.

### TrainingDays.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TrainingDays")
public class TrainingDays implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="TD_Id")
    private int TD_Id;

    @Column(name="T_Days")
    private String T_Days;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="trainingDays")
    private Set<TrainingTime> trainingTime;

    public int getTD_Id() {
        return TD_Id;
    }

    public void setTD_Id(int tD_Id) {
        TD_Id = tD_Id;
    }

    public String getT_Days() {
        return T_Days;
    }

    public void setT_Days(String t_Days) {
        T_Days = t_Days;
    }

    public Set<TrainingTime> getTrainingTime() {
        return trainingTime;
    }

    public void setTrainingTime(Set<TrainingTime> trainingTime) {
        this.trainingTime = trainingTime;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
}
```

### TrainingTime.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TrainingTime")
public class TrainingTime implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="TT_Id")
    private int TT_Id;

    @Column(name="time")
    private String time;

    @Column(name="desc")
    private String desc;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TD_Id")
    private TrainingDays trainingDays;

    public int getTT_Id() {
        return TT_Id;
    }

    public void setTT_Id(int tT_Id) {
        TT_Id = tT_Id;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public TrainingDays getTrainingDays() {
        return trainingDays;
    }

    public void setTrainingDays(TrainingDays trainingDays) {
        this.trainingDays = trainingDays;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
}
```

Always try to apply mappings after declaring all the columns.

Comment: Thank. but as per your code its still not creating an table of TrainingTime.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution of this issue,

in TrainingTime Pojo class i have created one variable named "Desc", and i found that this keyword is already reserved, so can name any variable like this.